# Llamar Stored Procedure en Java con tipo de datos SYS_REFCURSOR como salida

Tags: java, oracle-11g, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando una aplicación de consola en JAVA, donde requiero ejecutar un **Stored Procedure** hecho en **Oracle**, dicho Stored Procedure tiene tres variables de entrada que son de tipo de dato String y dos de salida las cuales una es de tipo String y la ultima es de tipo SYS_REFCURSOR. El problema que tengo que al momento indicar los tipos de datos que me va a devolver este Stored Procedure, en Java no me reconoce el tipo de dato SYS_REFCURSOR.

Este el un ejemmplo de mi codigo en JAVA:

```
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;


try {
    connection = ConnectionConfiguration.getConecction();
    callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL sp_jobsMonitor_UpdateCurrentSt(?,?,?,?,?)}");
    callableStatement.setString(1, job.getJobName());
    callableStatement.setString(2, job.getExecutionStatus());
    callableStatement.setString(3, job.getExceptionID());
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.xxxx);

    callableStatement.executeUpdate();

    job.setExceptionMessage(callableStatement.getString(4));

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if (callableStatement != null) {
        try {
            callableStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
return "ok";
```

En la linea `callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.xxxx);`  es donde requiro indicar ese tipo de dato SYS_REFCURSOR.

Ya he intendo indicando el tipo de dato `Types.OTHER` e incluso `Types.VARCHAR` no se que estoy haciendo mal u omitiendo.

Saludos

NOTA: Los tipos de datos que uso se basan en los tipos de Datos de Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese tipo de cursores no están soportados por JDBC, solo se soporta vía Oracle. Para resolver esto, debes utilizar el tipo de dato de salida de Oracle:

```
import oracle.jdbc.*;

//...
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Fuente: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias. Solo tuve que descargar la libreria. ojdbc6.jar   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html